CSS/HTML fit label background box tightly to text
So i have a login page, where i have created a simple design i like with the input fields and their corresponding labels. As you can see from the below picture, i have moved the label  on top of the input fields top border and then made sure it sits on top with z-index.
This looks completely fine when the background is white, but when i change the background my problem is highlighted. As you can see the background "box" of the label is showing. I know i can just change to color of this, but what i really want is for it to be transparent. But if you make it transparent, you can see the top border of the input field (see picture also). Is there some way to fit the background box "tightly" to the text, or perhaps even make the height of the background box less than the text height?
Perhaps is there even a way to sort of save this input field and label design in some way so that it is its own thing from the start, and not something i sit and create on the spot thus introducing my problem.
HTML snippet:
import React from 'react';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';

<Stack direction="column" spacing={1}>
  <Stack direction="column" spacing={-0.85}>
    <label className="login_label" id="login_email_label" for="login_email">.email</label>
    <input className="login_input" type="email" id="login_email_input" name="login_email"/>
  </Stack> 
  <Stack direction="column" spacing={-0.85}>
    <label className="login_label" id="login_password_label" for="login_password">.password</label>
    <input className="login_input" type="password" id="login_password_input" name="login_password"/>
  </Stack> 
</Stack>

css snippet:
.login_label, .register_label{
    position: relative; 
    left: -2px;   
    width:max-content; 
    display: block;
    font-family: 'AvenirBold';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: gray;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0 1px; 
    z-index: 2;   
    user-select: none; 
}

.login_input, .register_input{
    height: 25px;
    font-family: 'AvenirDemi';
    z-index: 1;    
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}





Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Please a runnable example -. How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?

I don't know how well it will work with Stacks, but  and  will do what you want. Try the runnable code snippet.
I changed the inner  to a 
I replaced the  with a  to go with the fieldset
For demo purposes, I changed the outer  to a 
For demo purposes I changed the className's to class


.login_label, .register_label{
    position: relative;
    left: -2px;
    width:max-content;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'AvenirBold';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: gray;
    /* EDIT Leave the label background transparent */
    /* background-color: white; */
    padding: 0 1px;
    z-index: 2;
    user-select: none;
}

.login_input, .register_input{
    height: 25px;
    font-family: 'AvenirDemi';
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* EDIT Remove the border around the <input>, so it blends into the <fieldset> */
    border: 0px;
}

/* NOTE These .Stack settings are specific to my demo code */
.Stack {
  margin: 1rem;
  width: max-content;
}
.Stack.Dark {
  background-color: #B3B0B0;
}
.Stack.Light {
  background-color: white;
}
.Stack fieldset {
  background-color: white;
}
.Stack legend {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

/* NOTE These button settings are specific to my demo code  */
button.Big {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.5rem 4rem;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  background-color: #696969;
}
<div class="Stack Light">
  <fieldset class="Stack">
    <legend class="login_label">.email</legend>
    <input class="login_input" type="email" id="login_email_input" name="login_email"/>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="Stack">
    <legend class="login_label">.password</legend>
    <input class="login_input" type="password" id="login_password_input" name="login_password"/>
  </fieldset>

  <button class="Big">Login</button>
  <button class="Big">Back</button>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="Stack Dark">
  <fieldset class="Stack">
    <legend class="login_label">.email</legend>
    <!-- <label class="login_label" for="login_email">.email</label> -->
    <input class="login_input" type="email" id="login_email_input" name="login_email"/>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="Stack">
    <legend class="login_label">.password</legend>
    <!-- <label class="login_label" for="login_password">.password</label> -->
    <input class="login_input" type="password" id="login_password_input" name="login_password"/>
  </fieldset>

  <button class="Big">Login</button>
  <button class="Big">Back</button>
</div>




Yes mate! When you commented this i had actually come up with solution using fieldsets myself. After relentlessly searching on here for this problem i finally found some threads on it.
That being said, i really appreciate you - because if i had not found anything on it, your answer would have been exactly what i needed to look at. Thanks!
